# ViewPager, send page to last position?

Tags: android-viewpager

With an Android ViewPager showing multiple pages, is there a way to send a page to last position? All other pages would move up one index.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify your question?

If you want your view pager to show last page:

You can use  viewPager.setCurrentItem(POSITONOFYOURREQUIREDPAGE, true);